# jquery image slider without using <HEAD> tags?

Tags: jquery, slider

I need to use a jQuery slider on a page but I don't have access to the  tag for this page.  Is there a jQuery (or any other language) script that will allow me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What does a jQuery slider have to do with `<head>` tags? Are you just looking for an appropriate location for `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to include the jquery UI library but can't change the code in the head tag...it's not necessary to put the script includes in the head tag. In fact, placing you script tags just above the closing body tag is supposed to make the page render faster.